# DAC on a player with only HDMI and USB out

Tags: usb, analog, android, dac

I have an *nVidia Shield* box which outputs only by `HDMI`. You can also attach a `USB DAC` for audio output.

With no `line out` or anything else analog, would I be right in my belief that this box (and similar) is absolutely dependent on the `DAC` abilities of what it's outputing to, that it has no impact on the digitial to analog conversion internally; that if it outputs audio over `HDMI` it can only do so digitally and it's up to the `DAC` hardware of a television or reciever, and the quality of those components, to perform the audio conversion to analog unless a `USB DAC` is attached, in which case that takes on the same job.

Correct?

Comment: Yup. They saved the cost of DACs.